# How to add a Class into dynamically created DOM element or a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

The classes `category2`, `category3`, `category4` etc. are the dynamically created. I want to add and remove some class called `active` like `class="category2 active"`.

Here is the code where I have tried to add the .active class into that dynamically created class **dynamic-class***, but it's not working:

```js
if (count == 1) {
  $('.dynamic-class' + count).removeClass('active');
  $('.dynamic-class' + 2).addClass('active');
}
if (count == 2) {
  $('.dynamic-class' + count).removeClass('active');
  $('.dynamic-class' + 1).addClass('active');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="film_listing live_tv">
  <div class="col-sm-2"><img id="11665" class="dynamic-class1" src="images/movies/flowerstv.jpg"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><img id="11666" class="dynamic-class2" src="images/movies/flowerstv.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: classes are dynamically created or the dom element?

Comment: Where is `count` defined and what is its value? You're also missing the `.` prefix on your class selectors.

Comment: it is dynamic..

Comment: Your logic is also flawed. The second `if` cancels out the actions of the first.

Comment: It is just an example. the classes are in image tag are dynamically created. How can I add another dynamic class  into that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `.` when selecting by classname. Try below:

```
if (count == 1) {
    $('.dynamic-class' + count).removeClass('active');
    count++;
    $('.dynamic-class' + count).addClass('active');
}
if (count == 2) {
    $('.dynamic-class' + count).removeClass('active');
    count--;
    $('.dynamic-class' + count).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: classes are in image tag are dynamically created